# Prove or disprove f an integer is divisible by 4, then it is divisible by 8

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I need to know if I can prove or disprove if an integer is divisible by 4 then it is divisible by 8,for this question should i just show a value like 12 to show this statement is wrong or what?
How should I approach this question?

Comment: Yes, giving a counterexample (such as 12) is sufficient.

Comment: Yes,  4, 12, 20 etc. (all 4*(2k + 1)) are divisible by 4 and not by 8, and the statement is very much not true. I'm finding it very hard to believe that was asked as a serious question.  But, yes, showing a single counter example is enough to completely disprove a statement.

Comment: Square of a rational number is rational. how do i prove or disprove this statement

Comment: @Char let $x$ be a rational number, then $x=\frac{a}{b}$ for some  $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $x^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2} $ with  $ a^2,b^2 \in  \mathbb{Z}$, hence $x^2$ is rational .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample:   $4|4$ but $8\not| 4$.